# Touchlistener on activity switch from touch doesn't see the touch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm new to Android and couldn't figure this out or find any solutions that work.

I have a first activity that I want and is successfully switching to a 2nd activity when the user presses the screen from MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, and I want the 2nd activity to immediately switch to a 3rd activity when the user lifts his finger up, but the touchlistener on the 2nd activity does not respond until user lifts finger, presses again, and then lifts for a 2nd time.

Very simple code

```
public class BlueActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, RedActivity.class));
    }
    return true;
}
```

2nd One

```
public class RedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_red);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
    relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, OrangeActivity.class));
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: if you are not doing any thing in 2nd activity then why you need that??
you can directly launch 3rd activity rit...

Comment: I am planning on doing something in the 2nd activity, just hadn't gotten to that yet and was first trying to make the switching between activities work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this in **BlueActivity** because the onTouch method of RedActivity not called because event in the BlueActivity still running so try to put this in BlueActivity it'll work.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, RedActivity.class));
    }

 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, OrangeActivity.class));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That did not work. I think b/c it loses focus when the view switches, it never recieves an ACTION_UP

Comment: Actually, after trying that code again, I noticed it works if you touch during BlueActivity and immediately lift your finger then it will get an ACTION_UP, but if you touch and hold then lift your finger, then it never gets an ACTION_UP.